# How can I set a fixed fee sufficient for transaction success in bitcoind?

Tags: bitcoind, transaction-fees, blockspace-market, fee-estimation

I used to use `sendtoaddress` with `bitcoind` and a fixed `0.0001 btc` transaction fee in the wallet UI to do the job and every transaction was sent without any problems.

Since version `v0.12.0` I can see that the fee is not fixed, plus some transactions don't transmit to the network.

How can I send transaction with `bitcoind` that will be 100% relayed ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
txconfirmtarget=1
```

If paytxfee is not set, include enough fee so transactions begin confirmation on average within n blocks (default: 6).

So putting it equal to 1 will automatically set the fee to be included in the next block.

Note that this isn't a "fixed amount solution".

Comment: Since 0.14, you cannot ask for a confirmation target of 1 anymore, because there is basically no fee that can guarantee inclusion into the next block (it may happen within seconds, giving miners not enough time to include it). If you ask for 1, it will be rounded up to 2, or whatever number sufficient data is available for.